# expo OTA contains .env secrets React-Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, ota

Problem: expo OTA bundle contains plain secrets.

I have a question regarding "what is the right way to fix it".

We have a expo react-native app written in typescript.
This app call an API endpoints, after initial auth and OAuth2 token retrival (not that important).

API auth requires username/password, those are stored as environmental variables e.g in `.env` file.
Then secrets are used in code to build a request in the following way:

```
import { USER, PASSWORD, API_URL } from "@env";
....

private async _authenticate() {

    const body = `username=${USER}&password=${PASSWORD}`;
    const response = ......
```

So far so good.

But since we like the idea of OTA and expo combination, we use
`expo export --public-url $EXPO_UPDATE_URL`.
Bundle is generated and then placed on server.

But close inspection reveals that the bundle (publicly available for mobile app to download) contains raw,plain passwords.
That seems like a massive security flaw.
[image]

Are we doing it "the wrong" way?
How should we fix it to at least obfuscate expo bundle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use [Hermes with expo](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-hermes/), Hermes converts your js bundle to Bytecode, even though you can disassemble it but it adds extra overlay(obfuscate)!